# How to set parameter variable for TestNg suite file from Maven POM

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have multiple TestSuites files.

And I want to set parameter variable in my suite files from POM file. But I couldn't get any suggestion from Google search.

Could anyone help me how can I perform it.

### For example.

ABC.xml [File #1]

```
<parameter name="property_file" value="C:/a.properties" />
```

DEF.xml [File #2]

```
<parameter name="property_file" value="C:/a.properties" />
```

---

And I want to set Property_file parameter value from Maven pom.

I want to set "C:/123.properties" for File #1 and "C:/456.properties" for File #2.

My suite file may look like_

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>ABC.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <suiteXmlFile>DEF.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

---

I don't want to set parameter in TestNG file, I want to do it from POM file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can filter with the maven ressources plugin. Have a look:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

If the article doesn't answer all your questions, don't hesitate to ask.

In summary you can do something like this:

```
<project>
   ...
   <properties>
      <suiteXmlFile>ABC.xml</suiteXmlFile>
   </properties>
   ...
   <build>
   ...
      <resources>
         <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
         </resource>
         ...
      </resources>
      ...
   </build>
   ...
</project>
```

and in your xml file within the resources folder you use

```
<parameter name="property_file" value="${suiteXmlFile}" />
```

What is not possible (at least in a simple way) is to implement a maven magic that interprets the same property differently within each xml file. In this case you have to use differently named properties. (e.g. suiteXmlFile1, suiteXmlFile2)

Answer (score 0):

@niklas-p 's answer is good but in the case of test resources, you should use `testResources` instead.

```
<project>
   ...
   <properties>
      <property_file>C:/a.properties</property_file>
   </properties>
   ...
   <build>
   ...
      <testResources>
         <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
         </testResource>
         ...
      </testResources>
      ...
   </build>
   ...
</project>
```

Then, the filtered resources will be located in the `${project.build.testOutputDirectory}` directory:

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/ABC.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <suiteXmlFile>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/DEF.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

And in suite files:

```
<parameter name="property_file" value="${property_file}" />
```

Comment: Hi, I am new in this so I find Test Resource concept little tricky.

I just want to send "property_file" parameter for any testsuite xml.

So, Is it mandatory to use resource concept for this type of configurations.

And Thanks All to answer my question.